# Titanium: Why is the callback for startActivityForResult not happening?

Tags: android, android-intent, titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I am trying to get the IntentCookbook sample app from Forging Titanium (episode 9) to work.

Code here: https://github.com/appcelerator-developer-relations/Forging-Titanium/tree/master/ep-009/IntentCookbook

Most exaples work fine, but when the "startActivityForResult(intent, callback)" function is being used, the callback isn't excecuted. Also when doing the 'Capture and view image' the application will be displayed in landscape orientation after returning from the camera (I assume because it doesn't realise the camera stuff is done and it should return to portrait orientation.)

I am using Titanium sdk 1.8.2 and the V8-runtime. I tried this on the emulator (android sdk 2.3.3 and 3.0) and two actual devices running 2.3.3 and 2.3.4 but they all exhibit the same behaviour.

Could anyone tell me why this isn't working for me?

EDIT: When trying 'Pick and edit contact' this is the log output.

```
I/ActivityManager(   62): Displayed com.appcelerator.IntentCookbook/org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity: +350ms
I/ActivityManager(   62): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.PICK typ=vnd.android.cursor.dir/person cmp=com.android.contacts/.ContactsListActivity } from pid 413
I/ContactsListActivity(  194): Called with action: android.intent.action.PICK
I/ActivityManager(   62): Displayed com.android.contacts/.ContactsListActivity: +511ms
W/InputManagerService(   62): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@405efe50 (uid=10006 pid=194)
```

Comment: Some error log from logcat would be helpful.

Comment: From the sounds of it, there is nothing to be posted from logcat.

Comment: I added something from the log, hope it's helpful.

Comment: I'm having this problem with the latest version of Titanium, 2.1.

Answer (score 1):

I know that the question is old, but if someone is still facing a similar problem, maybe my solution could work. My code wasn't working when I had it like this:

```
var activity = Ti.Android.currentActivity;
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, function(e){
    // your code
});
```

But then it worked after I had changed it like this:

```
var activity = $.yourWindowId.getActivity(); // this should be the window you are on
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, function(e){
    // your code
});
```